# Call external api via input field data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Assume a 'part number' input field that is not in a form tag. When the user enters a value, the onblur or a button next to the input field should query an external site via that site's API, and return the 'product name' value.

I have the code that will use the API to return the value. But how to structure the input field so that it calls the API code?

I think I need an AJAX call, but still a noob on Ajax stuff. What code would be used to process the string in the input field. (Note that there is no form tag associated with the input field.) (I primarily use PHP.)

Comment: You can attach an eventhandler to the button or use an onclick event to invoke a function, which will query the data from the API. What method you use (ajax, etc) to query the data will depend on the API. Can we get details of the API or can you add the API code?

Comment: The API code is Amazon's API.The function does the API thing with the appropriate parameters, and the code grabs the needed data and returns an array of the info I need.

Answer (score 0):

In response to the question and subsequent comments, conceptually it would work as follows then.

The HTML Markup:

```
<input type="text" id="userInput"> <!--Text input of product id from user-->
<button id="btn">Get Product Name</button> <!--Button to invoke API request-->
<p id="productName"></p> <!--Element used to display product name result from API-->
```

The Javascript:

```
//Attach an event listener to the button. 
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function(){

    //Get the id of product the user entered
    var productId = document.getElementById("userInput").value;

    //pass productId to the Amazon API

    //receive product name from API

    //Display product name received
    document.getElementById("productName").innerHTML = //The product name received from API

});
```

Comment: Thanks. But if the productId is JS variable, how do I pass that to the PHP function?  I *think* maybe $productID = "<script>document.getElementByID('userInput').value;</script>";   at the beginning of the PHP function that does the API call ??

Comment: @RickHellewell  It's best practice to keep your PHP separate. Ajax would be perfect to pass a Javascript variable to your PHP. What makes Ajax even more suitable is that it has callback functions ```success```, ```fail```, and ```error```, which you can use to handle the data returned from the API (in your case the product name). Highly recommend. Hope it helps.